# Entering the US twice within one week on B2 visa

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I'm meeting my American family in the US. Next day we're flying to Mexico, and then we'll return 5 days later. 2 days after that I'm flying out of the US.

I know on an ESTA passport a visit to Mexico doesn't reset the US clock so technically I will not have left the US, but does that also apply to B2 tourist visa passports?

Answer (score 2):

The particular rule about visits to Canada and Maxico "not resetting the clock" applies, as far as I know, only to the Visa Waiver Program, and not to travelers with visas.

However, even if it did, I can't see how it would create any problem for you, since your *final* exit from the US will only be about a week after you *first* entered. No matter whether any clock is or is not reset, this is by all means an unproblematic short visit.

---

You will have a problem if your B-2 visa only allows a single entry, though -- since your plan clearly involves entering the United States twice. But that is not connected to any "resetting of clocks". Even under the VWP rules, the result of the neighbor-country rule is not that you "did not leave the US and reenter", but merely that at your admission the *second* time you enter will be limited to until 90 days after the *first* entry. Both entries are real entries, though.

However, it seems to be quite rare for B-2 visas to be issued for a single entry only. The visa does have an "Entries" field, but all examples I could quickly find on Google Image Search showed this fill out with M(ultiple). There are scattered claims on the net that certain nationalities are more at risk for getting a single-entry visa, but no hard data.

Comment: Single entry visa wouldn't be an issue. Automatic visa revalidation allows you to re-enter from Mexico or Canada in a situation like this, even with an expired/used visa.

Comment: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1218/~/automatic-revalidation-for-certain-temporary-visitors